# Load content while scrolling a div with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, jquery-scrollable

I need to load content while scrolling a **div**, not window.
That's my CSS code:

```
#sidebar{
 width:30%;
 float:right;
 height:455px;
}
#video_list{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

And this is my html code:

```
<div id="sidebar" >
 <!-- other -->
 <div id="video_list">
 </div>
</div>
```

Video_list is scrollable and the content is loaded by ajax call.
When I go to the end of scrollbar i need to load content again.
How can i determine the height of scrollable div ?
I tried this:

```
if ($("#video_list").scrollTop()==$("#video_list").height()){
  loadContent();
 }
```

but it doesn't work !

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work". Do you get errors? Is the callback called? try to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the scroll height you can do this:

> $("#video_list")[0].scrollHeight;

Comment: OK, but don't work:

$('#video_list').scroll(function (){
  if($("#video_list").scrollTop()==$("#video_list")[0].scrollHeight){
        loadContent();
      }
} );

Comment: Ok i solve it.
I have to sum with #sidebar height:

if($("#video_list").scrollTop()+$("#sidebar").height()==$("#video_list")[0].scrollHeight)